# Как зациклить .png фон по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

**Здравствуйте!** 
Имеется некоторый фон, его я прикрепил.
 Необходимо сделать так, чтобы он, выходя за границу своего максимального значения по вертикали, красиво продолжался без артефактов.
Как это можно сделать?

Спасибо[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfOJG.png)

Comment: Покажите вашу разметку

Comment: @RogatnevNikita, там ничего особенного
.items-section-oblacheniya-select {
    height: 80vh;
    background-size: contain;
    background: url(/img/fon_2.png);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала тебе не нужна такая большая картинка. Достаточно вот такого кусочка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.div{
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/obTI6.png');
  height: 5000px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Если хочешь склеить все же свой, то обрежь в своей картинки внизу белую полосу, которая дает артефакт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]